# Why isn't AngularJS form handler method being called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Why doesn't the AngularJS form shown below call its `confForm()` handler method in the controller?**  I know that the controller is hooked up to the view, because the view prints the values of the `confirmStatus` and `wleadid` variables that are set in the controller.  However, the validation warnings in the form are not printed in the user's browser, and nothing happens when the user clicks on the submit button.  Specifically, there are two SYSO commands in the `confForm()` handler method below that never get printed to the console, thus showing that the method is not fired.  **What specific changes need to be made to the code below in order to get the `confForm()` form handler method to run?**

Here is the view html:

```
confirmStatus: {{ confirmStatus }}
<br>
webleadid: {{ wleadid }}
<div ng-show="confirmStatus=='success'">
<h1>Some title</h1>
<h2>Some message.</h2>
<form name="confirmForm" ng-submit="confForm(phoneForm.$valid)" novalidate>
    Cell Phone number: 
    <input type="hidden" name="someData" ng-value="wleadid" />
    <input type="text" name="phonenum1" ng-model="resultphone.phonenum1" required />
    <input type="text" name="phonenum2" ng-model="resultphone.phonenum2" required />
    <input type="text" name="phonenum3" ng-model="resultphone.phonenum3" required />
    <p ng-show="phoneForm.phonenum1.$error.required && !phoneForm.phonenum1.$pristine" class="help-block">All 3 parts of cell phone number are required.</p>
    <p ng-show="phoneForm.phonenum2.$error.required && !phoneForm.phonenum2.$pristine" class="help-block">All 3 parts of cell phone number are required.</p>
    <p ng-show="phoneForm.phonenum3.$error.required && !phoneForm.phonenum3.$pristine" class="help-block">All 3 parts of cell phone number are required.</p>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="phoneForm.$invalid" >Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript controller, which is able to populate the confirmStatus and webleadid variables to the view html, but which is not processing the form submit button clicks:

```
angular.module('confirm', []).controller('confirm', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

 // set the default value of our number
$scope.confirmStatus = "success";
$scope.wleadid = "30";

$scope.confForm = function(isValid) {
    console.log("inside confForm")
    if (isValid) {
        console.log("confForm is Valid!")
        var funcJSON = {type:"resultphone", wleadid: $scope.wleadid, phonenum1: $scope.phonenum1, phonenum2: $scope.phonenum2, phonenum3: $scope.phonenum3, };
        console.log('form is valid.  about to post... ')
        $http.post('/submit-phone', funcJSON).then(function(response) {
            $scope.confirmStatus = response.data.content;
        });
    }
};

});
```

Comment: Where is phoneForm defined?

Comment: @Mike Perhaps nowhere.  I am still learning AngularJS.

Comment: If you want to validate the form you are using, try passing in "confForm(confirmForm.$valid)" instead of "confForm(phoneForm.$valid)"

Comment: Does it work without the check for `$valid`? (if you just call `confForm()` by itself?)

Comment: @Mike Your change got the REST service to be called on the server.  But oddly, there is no console output from the AngularJS SYSO.  And there is still no form validation.  Are you willing to comment on those elements?  I can also mark an answer you submit as accepted, but to avoid cluttering the site with similar questions, I would appreciate your comments on the other aspects of the question, if you are willing.

Comment: @CodeMed, see answer. I think you accidentally validated the wrong form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are validating a form you aren't submitting. Change the instances of 'phoneForm' to 'confirmForm' in your HTML and you should get the behaviour your expecting.

```
confirmStatus: {{ confirmStatus }}
<br>
webleadid: {{ wleadid }}
<div ng-show="confirmStatus=='success'">
<h1>Some title</h1>
<h2>Some message.</h2>
<form name="confirmForm" ng-submit="confForm(confirmForm.$valid)" novalidate>
    Cell Phone number: 
    <input type="hidden" name="someData" ng-value="wleadid" />
    <input type="text" name="phonenum1" ng-model="resultphone.phonenum1" required />
    <input type="text" name="phonenum2" ng-model="resultphone.phonenum2" required />
    <input type="text" name="phonenum3" ng-model="resultphone.phonenum3" required />
    <p ng-show="confirmForm.phonenum1.$error.required && !confirmForm.phonenum1.$pristine" class="help-block">All 3 parts of cell phone number are required.</p>
    <p ng-show="confirmForm.phonenum2.$error.required && !confirmForm.phonenum2.$pristine" class="help-block">All 3 parts of cell phone number are required.</p>
    <p ng-show="confirmForm.phonenum3.$error.required && !confirmForm.phonenum3.$pristine" class="help-block">All 3 parts of cell phone number are required.</p>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="confirmForm.$invalid" >Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you and +1 for helping me see this.  Your changes get the server-side REST service to be called, and the submit button in the view is disabled until all three fields have values.  But yet **THERE IS NO WARNING PRINTED WHEN THE FIELDS ARE EMPTY. AND THERE IS NO CONSOLE PRINTOUT FROM THE CLIENT SIDE SYSO IN THE JAVASCRIPT FILE.**  I know that we have to keep questions concise.  If you have comments on the remaining issues, I would welcome them.  But if the remaining issues are not quickly resolved here, I will just post elsewhere.  Thank you again.